Image Mosaic Creation Fails in GeoServer
I am trying to make an image mosaic using REST and I’m only getting 500 errors.
My goal is to copy the configuration files and tiffs for the mosaic to the GeoServer data directory and then tell GeoServer that the mosaic exists.
Here are my specs:

GeoServer version 2.24.1
Postges/Postgis 14.8

This is what I’m doing:
Configured GeoServer to know about my Postgis datastore:
[]
Copied over the datastore.properties, indexer.properties, timeregex.properties, Look_Da_A_Mosaic.properties, and tiff file (GALWEM-GD__GLOBAL__Absolute_vorticity_20210525000000.tiff) to the directory I made at /var/GeoServer/data_dir/workspaces/weather/Look_Da_A_Mosaic
Sent the following curl command:
curl -v -u myuser:mypwd -XPUT -H “Content-type: text/plain” -d “file:///var/GeoServer/data_dir/workspaces/weather/Look_Da_A_Mosaic” http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/weather/coveragestores/Look_Da_A_Mosaic/file.imagemosaic

I can see that a store was created but the corresponding layer was not created.


Here are my configuration files:
datastore.properties:
SPI=org.geotools.data.postgis.PostgisNGDataStoreFactory
StoreName=weather:postgresWX

timeregex.properties:
regex=.([0-9]{14}).,format=yyyyMMddHHmmss

indexer.properties:
Schema=*the_geom:Polygon,location:String,crs:String,ingestion:java.util.Date
PropertyCollectors=TimestampFileNameExtractorSPItimeregex,CRSExtractorSPI(crs)
TimeAttribute=ingestion
Caching=false
AbsolutePath=false
AllowMultiThreading=true
USE_JAI_IMAGEREAD=false

Look_Da_A_Mosaic.properties:
Levels=0.4,0.4
Heterogeneous=false
AbsolutePath=false
Caching=false
ExpandToRGB=false
LocationAttribute=location
Name=GALWEM-GD__GLOBAL__Absolute_vorticity
TypeName=Look_Da_A_Mosaic
SuggestedSPI=it.geosolutions.imageioimpl.plugins.tiff.TIFFImageReaderSpi
SuggestedFormat=org.geotools.gce.geotiff.TIFFImageReaderSpi
CheckAuxiliaryMetadata=false
LevelsNum=1

This is the error in the GeoServer logs:
16:09:58,625 INFO [org.geoserver.rest.catalog] (default task-10) Auto-configuring coverage store: Look_Da_A_Mosaic
16:09:58,658 INFO [org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic] (default task-10) properties file doesn’t exist
16:09:58,658 INFO [org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic] (default task-10) Unable to load mosaic properties file
16:09:58,661 ERROR [org.geoserver.rest] (default task-10) Could not acquire reader for coverage.: org.geoserver.rest.RestException 500 INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR: Could not acquire reader for coverage.
at deployment.geoserver.war//org.geoserver.rest.catalog.CoverageStoreFileController.coverageStorePut(CoverageStoreFileController.java:246)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at deployment.geoserver.war//org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
at deployment.geoserver.war//org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
at deployment.geoserver.war//org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
at deployment.geoserver.war//org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
at deployment.geoserver.war//org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
at deployment.geoserver.war//org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
at deployment.geoserver.war//org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1072)
at deployment.geoserver.war//org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:965)
at deployment.geoserver.war//org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
at deployment.geoserver.war//org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:920)
at javax.servlet.api@2.0.0.Final//javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:526)

EDIT: As @user30184 suggested I tried making the mosaic through the UI. When I do that I see this error:


Can you create a store and a layer from your data without rest by using the user interface?

@user30184 I updated my question with the error I see when I go that way. I'm not sure what that error means: "Could not list layers for this store, an error occurred retrieving them: Failed to create reader from file:data/weather/Look_Da_A_Mosaic and hints...."
